# CustomListView OnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view, onitemclicklistener

I used a local database to fetch records and create a custom list view using that. The custom list view gets displayed perfectly. Problem is with Onitemclicklistener. It doesn't do anything on click. My aim is to send the position of clicked item to another activity. I implemented it but it's not working. 
Screenshot of list view - 
    https://www.dropbox.com/s/pz83i162sxdv2b0/Untitled.png?dl=0

Here is my MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ListView lv;
TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
String mydata,name,name1;
public String[] s1 = new String[50];
public int[] img = {R.drawable.rty, R.drawable.sf, R.drawable.rty};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    new MyData().execute();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, listclick.class);
            in.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}
public void abc(View v)
{
    Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,webform.class);
    startActivity(in);

}
public class MyData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        CustomAdapter cad = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, s1, img);
        lv.setAdapter(cad);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        getData();
        return null;
    }
}

public void getData()
{
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/abcd.php");
        HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity=response.getEntity();
        InputStream is=httpEntity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
        StringBuilder strbuilder=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            strbuilder.append(line);
        }
        is.close();
        mydata=strbuilder.toString();
        JSONArray obj=new JSONArray(mydata);
        for(int i=0;i<obj.length();i++)
        {

            JSONObject obj1=obj.getJSONObject(i);
            a.add(i,obj1.getString("Name"));
        }
        String[] s = new String[a.size()];
        s=a.toArray(s);
        s1 = s;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }


}


}
```

Here is second activity listclick.java

```
public class listclick extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listclick);
    Intent in=getIntent();
    String s1=in.getStringExtra("position");
   }
}
```

Here is Customlist.xml (layout file)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF9200"
android:clickable="true">
<TableRow>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sf"

        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Codewars 3.0"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Here is CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

Context c1;
String s1[];
int s2[];
CustomAdapter(Context c,String s[],int s3[])
{
    super(c,R.layout.listcustom,s);
    this.c1=c;
    this.s1=s;
    this.s2=s3;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater) c1.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v=li.inflate(R.layout.listcustom,null);
    TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText(s1[position]);






    return v;
}

}
```

Comment: does the item contain a custom view? you didn't show the code of CustomAdapter

Comment: I tried `android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" ` in each image and text view of customlist..but it still doesn't work

Comment: Have a look at CustomAdapter.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues in your code, the first is that your listcustom.xml has this set:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

If you are going to use the onItemClickListener() of a listview then you don't need that part.  Only set clickable if you are going to specifically set a View.OnCLickListner for ever item.  So just remove that line in the XML.

The next line that might cause issues is below:

```
inflate(R.layout.listcustom,null)
```

You should inflate items in a list like this:

```
inflate(R.layout.listcustom, parent, false);
```

Comment: thanks mate , it worked. I really needed this answer for my project.

Answer (score 0):

You might be starting the activity, but your old one is blocking the view. Try this:

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, listclick.class);
        in.putExtra("position", position);
        startActivity(in);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: No, that didn't work. Problem is that even if I put a toast in onclick, it doesn't get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do this work in `getView` method in adapter, touch event may be conflicted in listview.

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    ....

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        ....
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        view.setTag(position);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: I used intent in getView but startActivity method doesn't work there. `public void onClick(View v)
    {
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        Intent in=new Intent(getContext(),listclick.class);
        



    }
`

Comment: get the context from Activity, and call context.startActivity @NikhilKhurana

Comment: what the meaning of not working? onClick not called?

Comment: I tried a toast along with redirecting to other activity. But OnClick doesn't get called. Neither toast is displayed nor the other activity gets opened.